# Looking for membership style plugin with edit option

Tags: plugins, posts, customization, membership

I have had a search but not found what I'm looking for so far.

I am looking for a plugin which will provide a functionality on a site for the following:

- Use wants to sign up to my site, goes through a registration process
- Logs on to a user portal where they can add/edit/remove their own posts
- Offer free and paid memberships

I have looked at membership plugins but none seem to satisfy my need for the user to add/edit/remove their own posts and for their portal to NOT look like WordPress but more a "white label" solution if you will. I am not looking to offer premium content, I am looking to provide a place where people can place their own items in a listing style website.

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
gdude

Comment: i think you can use following plugin.not recomnended but i think this is best for you:[http://codecanyon.net/item/pixelmemberwordpress-membership-plugin/3153680](http://codecanyon.net/item/pixelmemberwordpress-membership-plugin/3153680)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the listings theme by [Woothemes](http://zfer.us/5WvQN) and there [woocommerce](http://zfer.us/gNeYu) solution offers subscriptions. These would provide the functionality you're after.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not really after a theme as I will be creating that myself. It's just a plugin I'm after (free or paid).

Comment: A theme can contain functionality too you know? And a theme doesn't mean a design.

Comment: I understand that and I have checked it out but it's just not what I'm after. Thanks though.